# RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `MYSERVER' does NOT match server name

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, centos6, openssl

I just launched a new website and installed a certificate on it and I started getting the following error messages in the ssl_erro_log:

```
[Fri Jun 21 15:24:53 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Jun 21 15:24:53 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `MYSERVER' does NOT match server name!?
```

Now my website specific config for SSL looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.65.61.12:443>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.co.uk mywebsite.co.uk

    DocumentRoot /data1/www/sites/www.mywebsite.com/public

    ErrorLog  /data1/log/httpd/www.mywebsite.com/error.log
    CustomLog /data1/log/httpd/www.mywebsite.com/access.log combined

    <Directory /data1/www/sites/www.mywebsite.com/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    ##SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /data1/www/ssl/www.mywebsite.com/www.mywebsite.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /data1/www/ssl/www.mywebsite.com/www.mywebsite.com.key

</VirtualHost>
```

The server that I'm using is:
CentOS 6 (64 Bit)
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that the CN for the certificate is MYSERVER while the FQDN of the web site is www.mywebsite.com, which doesn't match the CN of the certificate, which is why you get the error message. You need the CN of the certificate to match the FQDN of the web site.

Comment: if I updated the FQDN in /etc/sysconfig/network to the same name as the website then probably it will resolve this issue but if I need to host more then 1 website with certificates on this server then what?

Comment: Just to be sure I updated my FQDN to www.mywebsite.com and it still shows the same error